# ArcPy calculating string field gives ERROR 999999

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, field-calculator, error-999999

I'm trying to store a string value obtained from a loop through a tuple into a field called `ROW_1`. The code goes like this:

```
for creekclass in listOfClassTuples:

    (classname, Permanency, creekWidth, score) = creekclass
    arcpy.AddMessage(int(score))

    bufferDistance = creekWidth*0.5
    if crossingType == "INTERSECT":
        stringBuffer = ""
    else: 
        stringBuffer = "%s Meters" % str(bufferDistance)
        arcpy.AddMessage(str(bufferDistance))
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(sourceLayer, "JUST_SELECTED", fieldName +" = '"+ classname + "'")
        #arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("JUST_SELECTED", "NEW_SELECTION", fieldName+" = '"+ classname + "'")
        #arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("JUST_SELECTED", "SUBSET_SELECTION", fieldName2+" = '"+ Permanency + "'")
        #arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("JUST_SELECTED", "A:\Temporary\TempLayer1.shp")                           
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(targetLayer, crossingType, "JUST_SELECTED", stringBuffer, "NEW_SELECTION")
        ## classname = classname.lower()

        if outputField1 != "":                                        
            arcpy.CalculateField_management(targetLayer, outputField1, classname)
            #arcpy.AddMessage(str(classname))
            #arcpy.AddMessage(str(outputField1))

            arcpy.CalculateField_management(targetLayer, outputField2, int(score) )

            arcpy.Delete_management("Just_selected")
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(targetLayer, "CLEAR_SELECTION")
```

The problem appears in the following line taken from the code above

```
if outputField1 != "":                                        
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(targetLayer, outputField1, classname)
```

when the variable `classname` is equal to "Virtual Flow":

```
classname = "Virtual Flow"
```

I get the following error:

Executing: CalculateField Big_Pipes ROW_1 "virtual flow" VB #
Start Time: Tue Sep 30 09:40:09 2014
General error executing calculator.
ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Expected end of statement
Failed to execute (CalculateField).

Comment: Here you have presented what appears to be a copy/paste from your code rather than a code snippet that can be copy/pasted into Python IDE ready to test. WHat is `listOfClasses` set to when your code starts?

Answer (score 1):

> when the variable classname is equal to "Virtual Flow":
>
> ```
>  classname =  "Virtual Flow"
> ```

A couple of things to check if it works when `classname` is equal to other values:

- Check the `outputfield1` field type.  If it's date or number field, you'll get an error since you're trying to set it to a string
- If `outputfield1` is a string field type, check it's length.  If it's shorter than 12 characters, you'll get an error.  If this is the case, either change the length of the field, or change it to this to truncate it.

Answer (score 0):

The default expression type for CalculateField is VB. You need to specify Python:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(targetLayer, outputField1, classname, "PYTHON_9.3")
```

[Documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000004m000000)