# Iterating through Calculate Field using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, error-000539

I have three shapefiles as points that I am trying to create new fields for and fill in the fields with a string descriptor. I am then trying to merge all three point files deleting every field but keeping the `type` field. The code is below:

```
fieldnames = ['Type','Type','Type']
shapefiles = ['Flowpp1.shp','RoadPP1.shp','InletPP.shp']
expression = ["Stream","Road",'!Element!']
for i,x,j in zip(shapefiles,fieldnames,expression):
    arcpy.AddField_management(i,x,"TEXT",25,"","","","")
    arcpy.management.CalculateField(i,x,j,'PYTHON',"TEXT")

fieldMappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()
fieldMappings.addTable(shapefiles)
for field in fieldMappings.fields:
    if field.name not in ['Type']:
        fieldMappings.removeFieldMap(fieldMappings.findFieldMapIndex(field.name))

arcpy.management.merge(shapefiles,home + '/PourPoints.shp', filedMappings)
```

I am running into a name error when I get to the `arcpy.management.CalculateField` function.
What am I doing wrong?

The error is:

> ExecuteError: ERROR 000539: Error running expression: Stream
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> NameError: name 'Stream' is not defined

The goal is for the type filed for `Flowpp1.shp` to be `"Stream"`, `Roadpp1` to be `"Road"`, and `Inlet.shp` to be the row equivalent value in the `!Element!` field.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer to my question from [ArcPy calculating string field gives ERROR 999999](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115570/arcpy-calculate-string-field-any-ideas-what-how-to-fix-this)

The issue was in my `expression` list. The original did not include `''` around the field value ie `'"FIELD_VALUE"'`.

Answer (score 0):

Since this post two new tools have been added to the toolbox that will simplify your code. They are [Add Fields](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/add-fields.htm) and [Calculate Fields](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-fields.htm). This may be of interest to others seeking similar solutions.